# Question about center coordinate definition in region proposal networks

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, yolo

In the [YOLOv2 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf), page 3, it states that region proposal networks predicts $t_x$ and $t_y$ where $(x,y)$ center coordinates are calculated as:

$$x=t_x*w_a-x_a$$
$$y=t_y*h_a-y_a$$

such that for $t_x = 1$ would shift the box to the right by the width of the anchor box (subscript a). If so, I'm confused as to why in the equation we have $-x_a$ instead of $+x_a$ in such a case. In the [R-CNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf) they define $t_x$ as $(x-x_a)/w_a$.